# Eclipse Kepler crashes regularly with java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: linux, eclipse, unknown-host

My Eclipse Kepler on Opensuse 13.1 crashes regularly (about 5 times a day). In the error log I see this:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: chmalap.site: chmalap.site: Name or service not known
>       at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)

chmalap is the hostname of my pc on our local network... but why is he trying to look this up? My Eclipse is quite recent (8.2.1 and I didn't configure much settings. I have EGit and SVN plugins installed. Any ideas?

Here is the full crash information

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-01-28 16:43:31.135
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.rse.core 4 0 2014-01-28 16:43:35.330
!MESSAGE Unexpected Exception
!STACK 0
java.net.UnknownHostException: chmalap.site: chmalap.site: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.getLocalMachineName(RSECorePlugin.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSEPreferencesManager.getDefaultPrivateSystemProfileName(RSEPreferencesManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSEPreferencesManager.initDefaults(RSEPreferencesManager.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEPreferenceInitializer.initializeDefaultPreferences(RSEPreferenceInitializer.java:23)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper$1.run(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.runInitializer(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.node(DefaultPreferences.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.getDefaultPreferences(PreferenceForwarder.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.getInt(PreferenceForwarder.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.rse.logging.Logger.initialize(Logger.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.rse.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.rse.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.getLogger(RSECorePlugin.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEInitJob.<init>(RSEInitJob.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEInitJob.<clinit>(RSEInitJob.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.rse.internal.ui.RSEUIStartup.earlyStartup(RSEUIStartup.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: chmalap.site: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    ... 28 more
```

EDIT: At the suggestion of Greg-449, I deactivated RSE UI... yet my eclipse just crashed again. This time only these errors were present in the error log (they were already present in the error log before; but always before the crash; it didn't seem to me they were present at the moment of the crash)

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-01-29 09:14:02.117
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-01-29 09:14:02.117
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+CTRL+C:
Binding(ALT+CTRL+C,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog.core.actions.KeyActionCommand,Insert ChangeLog entry,
        Insert a ChangeLog entry,
        Category(org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog,Changelog,Changelog key bindings,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@1b31dee,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.textEditorScope,,,system)
Binding(ALT+CTRL+C,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog.core.actions.KeyActionCommand,Insert ChangeLog entry,
        Insert a ChangeLog entry,
        Category(org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog,Changelog,Changelog key bindings,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@1b31dee,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.compare.compareEditorScope,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-01-29 09:14:02.117
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+CTRL+P:
Binding(ALT+CTRL+P,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog.core.preparechangelog2,Prepare Changelog In Editor,
        Prepares ChangeLog in an editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog,Changelog,Changelog key bindings,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@139ed49,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.textEditorScope,,,system)
Binding(ALT+CTRL+P,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog.core.preparechangelog2,Prepare Changelog In Editor,
        Prepares ChangeLog in an editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog,Changelog,Changelog key bindings,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@139ed49,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.compare.compareEditorScope,,,system)
```

just to be on the safe side I removed one of each of these shortcuts since I don't use them... but they don't seem to be the critical errors to me

Comment: I flagged this question for removal: The problem seems to lie somewhere else... I'll start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be Eclipse RSE (Remote System Explorer) doing some initialization but running in to a problem with InetAddress.getLocalHost.

If you are not using RSE you should be able to stop this initialization by going to `Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown`.  Uncheck the `RSE UI` check box, this should stop the RSE initialization from running during Eclipse start up.

Update:
It looks like this might be [Eclipse bug 323606](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323606). The bug report says it caused by:

> Initialize system using DHCP and don't register ip address/hostname with DNS

Comment: thanks for the tip: I unchecked the RSE UI and come back to you if I note some different behavior (crash or no crash within this day)